# Kendo TreeList customize sort operation

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

Is it possible to customize sort operation in Kendo TreeList, version Kendo UI jQuery?
In other words. Is there any possibility to take over the sorting event by the selected column?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a [columns.sortable.compare](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treelist/configuration/columns.sortable.compare) function that would be executed when the user clicks on a column to sort the dataItems. [For example](https://dojo.telerik.com/uBUTegUk), you could sort by FirstName length, rather than alphabetically.

```
columns: [{ field: "FirstName", 
            title: "First Name",
            sortable:{
             compare: function(a, b) {
               if(a.FirstName.length > b.FirstName.length){
                 return 1;
               }

               if(a.FirstName.length < b.FirstName.length){
                 return -1;
               }
               if(a.FirstName.length == b.FirstName.length){
                 return 0;
               }
             }
           } 
         },
        ...
        ],
```